# CakePHP Model not displaying accurate DB info

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model

So there is an admin on this site I'm working on, and he has to insert a value for a quote (which is then saved in the database). Then the user on another session needs to be able to refresh his page and see the new quote. However, its not displaying the new value because (I assume) there is a cached version of the Model already in use. How do I refresh this? I tried load Model, but since the data I actually need is a hasMany of the model I would load, it's not helping.

Comment: It's not model caching, as cakephp always recache it when a new was inserted/updated. Are you sure value is inserted? If yes, how do you retrieve it to show it for user?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific regarding what type of caching is in place.  Try looking at the bottom of your `Config/bootstrap.php` file to see if you have redis, or memcache...etc running.